# Extract data from multidimensional numerical array

Tags: php, arrays, extract

I have 2 dimensional array that is filled with data from the table.

I would like to *extract each value and use it for calculation and save the result into new array*.

**For example:**

```
$array[0][0] + 5 =  $result0

$array[0][1] + 35 = $result1

$array[0][2] + 55 = $result2

$array[0][3] + 15 = $result3

$array[0][4] + 75 = $result4
```

And then repeat the same calculation for whole next array in main array and all the others.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [ID] => 1
            [1] => 0
            [name] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [date] => 0
            [3] => 5
            [number] => 5
            [4] => 0
            [size] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [ID] => 2
            [1] => 0
            [name] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [date] => 0
            [3] => 3
            [number] => 3
            [4] => 0
            [size] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [ID] => 3
            [1] => 0
            [name] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [date] => 0
            [3] => 7
            [number] => 7
            [4] => 0
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract each element from the two dimensional array  use a foreach loop like shown below and Declare a new array and add updated values in the array after changing.

```
$cars = array
      (
      array(1,"id"=>100,"name"=>96),
      array(0,"id"=>60,"name"=>59),
      array(5,"id"=>110,"name"=>100)
      );



$result= array();


  foreach ($cars as $v1) { 
    foreach ($v1 as $v2) { 
        $result[]= $v2+5; 
    } 
} 
  print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this doesn't solve my problem. I would like to each separate $v2 have a different rule:
for example:
$array[0][0] = $v2 + 10
$array[0][1] = $v2 + 13
$array[0][2] = $v2 + 15
$array[0][3] = $v2 + 83
etc

Comment: Can you explain that how you are using the rules? Are the values stored in any other array?

Comment: This values are stored as variables defined by user.

Comment: Then you just need to replace $result[]= $v2+5; with $result[]= $v2+$uservar;. It will work fine.